# AVG & Windows Firewall block python 2.7 using PyScripter 2.5.3 (32-bit)

Tags: python, pyscripter

My first exposure to Python; maybe normal? Have tried Python 2.7.3 from both Python.org & ActivePython (2.7.2.5). When I run PyScripter 2.5.3, AVG interrupts and objects to python.exe. Have tried to reinstall python in several different folders and sometimes Windows Firewall pops up before AVG.  Running python.exe directly does not trigger AVG or Windows Firewall. Not sure what's going on here.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure either. Maybe PyScripter just does something weird and dangerous when it tries to find the python.exe. I recommend finding another IDE.

I personally use the PyDev plugin for Eclipse. I love it because I can also use other plugins and tooling already in my Eclipse environment (like Mercurial version control). That is what I have the most success with.